# Systemd interaction with Minecraft server

Tags: 18.04, systemd, minecraft, administration

As you do when you're bored, you set up a Minecraft server for you and your friends. I'm trying to make this constructive so I'm learning systemd.

My question is if there is a way to interact with the console this way? I understand I could send signals to it, but I'm hoping I can foreground it somehow and still monitor things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor by reading `logs/latest.log`, located in the minecraft directory. That log includes all console output.

- Example: My Minecraft Server runs under separate system user (not me, not root), so my minecraft directory is `/home/minecraft`, and my log is at `/home/minecraft/logs/latest.log`
- I monitor the file using the 'less' application: `less -F /home/minecraft/logs/latest.log`

Answer (score 0):

You can define `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` in your minecraft systemd unit file under service section. Below is example.

```
[Service]
....
......
StandardOutput=/var/minecraft/minecraft.log
StandardError=/var//minecraft/error.log
```

In case you want to pass log to system log identifier (example `rsyslog`), define  `SyslogIdentifier=<your program identifier>`.